Visual Studio 2022 17.10.0 -Can we still revert to a previous version?
They used to have an option in the Visual Studio installer to revert to a previous version. With this latest update - 17.10.0 - I do not see any such option there. Has it moved or has it been removed?
This is what I see when I choose the "More" dropdown


The option is still there for me after updating to 17.10.0 from 17.9.x. Did you install version 17.10 fresh or did you update via the Installer from version 17.9?

No I have been updating to the most recent version for quite some time now.  So before this I had 17.9.x.  I've updated my question to illustrate what I see when I go to where you were showing me

My guess is the installation must have somehow triggered a fresh installation flag somewhere. You can try with the command line option for rolling back if you want to roll back, but I don't know if it will work if the option isn't there on the UI; I assume whatever controls it showing up there might impact whether the command will work, too.

Yeah I'm not gonna mess with command line.  I'll probably screw something up worse.  I can live with this for now.  Thanks anyway

@Joe. Fear not. I have been audacious enough to try the very straight-forward command suggested by TylerH! Got me the Installer UI saying hello and giving me a nice textbox stating in uncharacteristic clarity: "There is no previous version to rollback to."
